# Does the rate limit for Twitter application API calls count across all methods or on a per-method basis?

Tags: twitter

i'm writing my first twitter api app. It will only use application authentication, and the Twitter Docs say

> When using application-only authentication, rate limits are determined globally for the entire application.

but then immediately say

> If a method allows for 15 requests per rate limit window, then it allows you to make 15 requests per window — on behalf of your application.

The first suggests to me that the limiting is different from user-authentication, and that I have 15 total api requests per 15-min period, while the second suggests that it's still by method. Which is the correct interpretation? Can I still make 15 calls with one method then 15 calls with another? Or is it 15 total across all methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some playing around with the twitter rate calls, it looks like each method is given its own rate limit, but it's not further divided by users (since there are no users.) In other words, I can make 180 rate limit calls, 15 get follower list calls, and 15 user lookup calls per rate period, while if it were user-authenticated, it would be 180 per period per user, 15 per period per user, and 15 per period per user.

an example call for getting users rate limit::

```
{u'reset': 1415387359, u'limit': 15, u'remaining': 15}, u'/users/lookup': {u'reset': 1415387359, u'limit': 60, u'remaining': 60}, u'/users/suggestions/:slug/members': {u'reset': 1415387359, u'limit': 15, u'remaining': 15}, u'/users/suggestions/:slug': {u'reset': 1415387359, u'limit': 15, u'remaining': 15}, u'/users/show/:id': {u'reset': 1415387359, u'limit': 180, u'remaining': 180}, u'/users/suggestions': {u'reset': 1415387359, u'limit': 15, u'remaining': 15}, u'/users/profile_banner': {u'reset': 1415387359, u'limit': 180, u'remaining': 180}}
```

so definitely still by method, even if it's not further divided by user.